# Installing Jinja2 on a server without root access

Tags: python, root, setuptools, easy-install, jinja2

I am trying to install Jinja2 on a web server. I tried running the command "easy_install Jinja2" as they [suggested](http://jinja.pocoo.org/2/documentation/intro) and got an error:

> [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/test-easy-install-15897.write-test'

I thought that since this was a permission problem, I tried the same thing with "sudo". I was asked for a password and told I don't have permission.

I tried installing Jinja2 with "python setup.py" and ran into similar problems.

I contacted my web hosting company (DreamHost, in case that matters), and they said I had to pay for their VPS service to get root access. I would prefer to install this without paying extra. They said I may have some luck installing it to my home directory, but they wouldn't guarantee anything. Does anyone here know how to do this? I have never used Jinja2, easy_install, or setuptools in my life until just now, so I don't know much about any of these things.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for their answers. I think I will give up on this question, at least for the near future. Virtualenv looks cool, but it looks kind of tricky to install, and I think I am already dealing with enough unfamiliar stuff. I may just spend the $15 or so per month on their VPS service.

Answer (score 4):

You can probably use [virtualenv](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) for solve this.

Comment: Do you have any experience with this? It looks kind of tricky but I may be willing to try it. I would like to know if it is tricky to install, if it will work with my existing Python CGI scripts without too much trouble, if it will slow down my site a lot, and if there is anything else I should know before trying it.

Answer (score 1):

easy_install --user Jinja2

Comment: I tried typing that into the command line and I got this error: "error: option --user not recognized".

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread, but since I have just done what you were asking, here is how. You only need python installed for this method.

Download the get-pip file on your home directory:

```
wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
```

Run this command to install pip on your ~/.local:

```
python get-pip.py --user
```

To add your new ~/.local/bin folder to your path, run or add to .bash_profile:

```
export PATH=$PATH:~/.local/bin
```

To install Jinja2, run:

```
pip install --user Jinja2
```

Remember to always put --user when using pip.